# Python: Pause dropbox with API

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I am running `unittest` on my module and in the end I have a command to delete a temporary folder with all temporary files created for the tests. The problem is that my code will often fail due to the fact that dropbox is trying to sync at the same time.

I saw that there is a python module to work with dropbox's API. I was wondering how to use this module to temporarily pause the syncing of dropbox while the script is running.

Comment: If its just a tmp dir why wouldn't you put it outside of your dropbox?

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question, but: couldn't you move your entire project out of your dropbox?

Comment: The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to pause the desktop client.

Comment: @jjj Putting the temp folder outside the dropbox is not an option because that would require an absolute path, which I don't want to do because I'm not the only one that is running these tests.

Comment: @Kevin The project needs to stay in the dropbox.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the info. Do you know if there is a way to use the API to stop syncing a specific folder?

Comment: Why does this require an absolute path? Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just go up the directory tree until you are no longer in the dropbox dir? You can still get the absolute path for each user using `os.path.abspath` function.

Comment: @Miguel No, there isn't, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.